Embedding degree of an elliptic curve
I've been reading about the embedding degree of elliptic curves in Costello's "Pairings for Beginners".  The following equivalent conditions are given for the embedding degree (p51):

where $E$ is an elliptic curve defined over $F_q$, $r$ is a prime dividing $|E(F_q)|$, and $E[r] \subset E(\bar{F_q})$ denotes the $r$-torsion.
We know moreover that if $r$ is prime to the characteristic of $F_q$, then $E[r] = \mathbb{Z}_r \times \mathbb{Z}_r$.
The following example seems to contradict this: let $q=7$ and let $E$ be defined by $y^2 = x^3 +1$.  We have $|E(F_q)| = 12$, so choose $r=3$.  We can check that $E(F_q)$ contains only $3$ $r$-torsion points, and yet $r=3$ divides $6 = (q^1 - 1)$ (which should indicate that the embedding degree is $1$).
Not sure where my misunderstanding lies, any help greatly appreciated.

This is indeed an error. While the first two quantities are both equal to the degree $\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}} [\F_q(\zeta_r) : \F_q]$ of the field extension $\F_q(\zeta_r)/\F_q$, where $\zeta_r$ is a primitive $r^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, the third, which is $[\F_q(E[r]) : \F_q]$ may be strictly larger, exactly as you have found.
I am not a cryptographer, and hadn't heard of the term embedding degree until now, but according to the paper Constructing Pairing-Friendly Elliptic Curves with Embedding Degree 10 by David Freeman, embedding degree refers to the first two quantities.

Definition 2.1. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over a finite field $\F_q$, and let $n$ be a prime dividing $\#E(\F_q)$. The embedding degree of $E$ with respect to $n$ is the smallest integer $k$ such that $n$ divides $q^k − 1$.

However, the field extension $\F_q(E[r])$ generated by the coordinates of all $r$-torsion points of $E$ may be strictly larger than $\F_q(\zeta_r)$. This is stated in Proposition 1.11 (p. 14) of the masters thesis The Field of $N$-torsion Points of an Elliptic Curve over a Finite Field by Van Tuyl. (Here $E$ is an elliptic curve over the field $K$ and $K_{E,n} = K(E[n])$ is the $n$-torsion field of $E$.)

Proposition 1.11. Let $P = (x,y) \in E(\overline{K})$ be a point of order $n$, where $n$ is a prime distinct from $\operatorname{char}(K)$. Then $K(P, \zeta_n) = K_{E,n}$ or $[K_{E,n} : K(P, \zeta_n)] = n$.

And this latter case can occur, as shown in Example 4.2 (p. 39) of the thesis, and by the example you have found. Since $(0,1) \in E(\F_7)$ is a $3$-torsion point and $\F_7$ already contains a primitive $3^{\text{rd}}$ root of unity, namely $2$ (or $4$), then $K(P, \zeta_n) = \F_7$. And as you've noted
$$
E(\F_7)[3] = \{\infty, (0,1), (0,-1)\}
$$
contains only $3$ points, not all $9$, so by the proposition we must have $[K_{E,n} : K(P, \zeta_n)] = 3$. And indeed, over $\F_{7^3} = \F_7(\nu)$, we attain the rest of the $3$-torsion points:
\begin{align*}
E(\F_{7^3})[3] = \{\infty, (0,1), (0,-1), (\nu^{19},2), (\nu^{19},5), (\nu^{133},2), (\nu^{133},5), (\nu^{247},2), (\nu^{247},5)\} \, .
\end{align*}
(I computed these points using the computer algebra system Magma.)
The fact that $[\F_7(E[3]) : \F_7] = 3$ can also be seen using division polynomials. The third division polynomial, whose roots are the $x$-coordinates of the $3$-torsion points of $E$, is
$$
\psi_3(t) = t(3t^3 + 5)
$$
and the factor $3t^3 + 5$ is irreducible over $\F_7$, as it has no roots. Thus $[\F_7(E[3]) : \F_7] = 3$, so $\F_7(E[3]) = \F_{7^3}$.

@Viktor Vaughn's answer is pretty good and correct. However, for a cryptographer, embedding degree is only used for a pairing-friendly ordinary elliptic curve, that is, the endomorphism ring restricted to r-torsion points shall be a split Cartan subgroup of GL(2,r) (r splits in upstairs).
If an endomorphism ring restricted to r-torsion points is a Borel subgroup (r ramifies in upstairs), a r-division field is a degree r extension of a base field. Because the image of the action of the inertia group on a r-division field in upstairs is isomorphic to a Galois group of the residue field, and is isomorphic to a Borel subgroup of GL(2,r) of order r.
In the context of a pairing based cryptography, we want a base field to be a finite filed of a prime order q, and we want to select G1 and G2 (two independent cyclic subgroups), such that G1 = ker(π-1), and G2 = ker(π-q), wherein π is a Frobenius endomorphism restricted to r-torsion points. $π$ satisfies $x^2−(q+1)x+q$ $≡$ $(x−1)(x−q)$$≡0$ modulo r. It follows that $(π-1)(π-q)$ is a zero endomorphism restricted to r-torsion points. Here G1 and G2 are two r-torsion subgroups out of $r+1$ r-torsion subgroups of a r-torsion group, whose group structure may be decomposed as a direct product of G1 and G2) (when ker(π-1) is not equal to whole r-torsion group), where G1 locates at a base field, and G2 locates at an extension field, in order to satisfy DDH assumption. That is, a distortion map (a non-stabilizer endomorphism of G1 or G2) shall not exist.
In this context, a minimal finite extension of a base field, containing the multiplicative group of order r, shall be big enough to contain a r-division field (the r-division field is defined as a base field adjoined with all coordinates of r-torsion points).
The proof is the following:
The embedding degree (e) is defined as the degree of extension of a r-division field over a base field.
From Weil pairing theory, it is known that r-division field necessarily contains the multiplicative group of order r. Suppose k is the degree of minimal extension of a base field contains the multiplicative group of order r. So e is bigger than or equal to k.
Suppose a point $P ∈ ker(π − q) = G2$ exists, we have $π^k(P) = q^k(P) = P$.
It follows that (when q is a prime number) said point $P$ locates at a finite field of a cardinality $q^k$. As a result, $k = e$.

Can you use latex to format your math equations?
